# Apache Nifi with IOT sensors

Tags: iot, dataflow, apache-nifi

Im new to Apache Nifi , and I'm having a use case which i need to parse and decode different kind of messages from Sensors, transform and load the data in Hbase all my sensors send data every 10 minutes through an API via a post request, what I have done for now is a service with JAVA that listen on a specific port and do all the ETL dataflow, any idea how can I use Apache Nifi for this use case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use case sounds like the kind of data flow NiFi was built to handle, and NiFi has specific capabilities you will want.  NiFi has several processors that can help you implement an HTTP web service.

- [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/index.html) - Simple receive from HTTP to a flowfile via POST.
- [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/index.html) and [HandleHttpResponse](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html) - Combination of processors for better control of HTTP verbs and response codes based on the processing the flowfile.

NiFi also has processors for working with HBase, especially [PutHBaseJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.hbase.PutHBaseJSON/index.html) for inserting JSON source data into HBase.

In addition to these specific processors, NiFi has many processors for shaping and routing your data.  I recommend looking at some of the [Example Dataflow Templates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Example+Dataflow+Templates), some appear directly relevant to your case:

- [Hello NiFi Web Service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/Hello_NiFi_Web_Service.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1449369797000&api=v2)
- [Fun with HBase](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/Fun_with_HBase.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1449181773000&api=v2)